# Filter Observable<List<Object>> with another Observable<List<AnotherObject>>

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-android, rx-java2

Is there some way to achieve following?

I have two Observables,

- `Observable<List<String>> broadcastIdsObservable`.
- `Observable<List<EventData>> eventDatasObservable`.

Is there any way to filter the eventDatasObservable with the List inside of broadcastIdsObsevable? I need to get a `List<EventData>` with the `eventData` that satisfies the condition `eventData.getBroadcastId().equals(broadCastId)` where `broadCastId` is each item of broadcastIds.

I try different ways of use flatMap, map and Observable.concat... but I am not able to achieve it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [RxJavaJoins](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJavaJoins). You'll need to include

```
compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava-joins:0.22.0'
```

Then create the Join:

```
@NonNull
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private Func0<Observable<List<EventData>>> loadAndFilterEvents() {
    return new Func0<Observable<List<EventData>>>() {

        @Override
        public Observable call() {

            Observable<List<String>> broadcastIdsObservable = ...;
            Observable<List<EventData>> eventDatasObservable = ...;

            Plan0<List<EventData>> plan = JoinObservable.from(broadcastIdsObservable)
                                                        .and(eventDatasObservable)
                                                        .then(filterJoin);
            return JoinObservable.when(plan).toObservable();
        }

        private Func2<List<String>, List<EventData>, List<EventData>> filterJoin = (broadcastIds, events) -> {
            List<EventData> filtered = new ArrayList<>();
            for (EventData event : events) {
                if (broadcastIds.contains(event.getBroadcastId())) {
                    filtered.add(event);
                }
            }
            return filtered;
        };

    };
}
```

And subscribe to it:

```
Observable.defer(loadAndFilterEvents())
              .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
              .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
              .subscribe(filteredEvents -> Timber.d("Events: %s", filteredEvents),
                         Timber::e);
```